# Concrete example of zero section

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

I just learnt tangent bundle and I want to get some intuition about zero section (and sections in general). I'm even not clear about what the zero vector is in a tangent space--e.g. just consider $df_p:T_p\mathbb{R}=\mathbb{R}\to T_{f(p)}\mathbb{R}=\mathbb{R}$, is $0\in\mathbb{R}$ the zero vector in $T_{f(p)}\mathbb{R}$ (which gives a critical point)? Can someone explain a good concrete example of zero section to me?

Comment: It's not a good idea, to use $d$ as tangent map. $d$ is here reserved for the differential, that means $df:M \to {T^*}M$ is
a section of co-tangent bundle, $df(p) \in {T^*}_pM$ is a co-vector.

Comment: Here is a very basic example: Consider $S^1$, the unit circle. The tangent bundle of this manifold can be identified with the infinite cylinder $S^1\times \mathbb{R}$. You can think of the zero section to be the inclusion map $i:S^1\to S^1\times \mathbb{R}$ defined by $\theta\mapsto (\theta,0)$. I am not sure if this is helpful but its the most basic example I can think of.

Answer (score 7):

Recall the general definition of a section. Let $\pi:E\to B$ be a (vector) bundle. A section is a map $s:B\to E$, such that $\pi\circ s=id$. In other words, a section is a map $B\to E$ that carries any point in $B$ to some point in the fiber over it.

A section of the tangent bundle is just a vector field.

Assume now $E\to B$ is a vector bundle. Then the fiber over a point $p\in B$ is a vector space, and it has a zero element $0_p$. The zero section is the map $s:B\to E$ that carries any point $p$ to $0_p$.

**Edit**: If $E$ is the tangent bundle, the zero section can be thought of in two ways, depending on your idea of tangent vectors. If you think of tangent vectors as equivalence classes of paths, then the zero tangent vector $0_p$ is the equivalence class represented by the constant path $\gamma\equiv p$. If you think of tangent vectors as derivations, then $0_p$ is the zero derivation, which maps every function to $0$.

Comment: Could you say something about my question on zero vector in tangent space?

Comment: @Vladimir: The tangent space ${T_p}M$ is a vectorspace, elements look like ${v_p} = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {{v^i}} \frac{\partial }{{\partial {x^i}}}(p)$, if $\dim (M) = n$.
The zero-vector of ${T_p}M$ is just ${0_p} = (p,0)$
in local coordinates.

Comment: @Vladimir Please read the edit in my answer.